# How do you remove the trash left by previous domain name owner?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains

So, I recently bought a domain name from Bluehost. Soon, I realized the domain name used to belong to someone else before I bought it. Now, the problem I am facing is that there are a few trash files that get crawled by all kinds of bots when they access my domain website which belonged to the previous domain. There is no way I can access those files on my cPanel server.

My website got flagged as malicious by Google Ads probably due to their files using 'http' calls while all my pages run on https. I did find a work-around to the mixed content problem by creating blank files and folders of the same name on my server that were causing http calls, and setting up redirects to my homepage. But google ads still flags my website as malicious content. It came up as clean in sucuri malware scan after resolving the mixed content issue.

Is there any way I can remove all the junk files that were left associated to my domain by the previous domain owner? If I choose to ignore it and let things be as they are, will it be a problem for me in the future? Should I just buy another domain name that didn't belong to anyone in the past and move my website there?

Update: I have confirmed on search console that the pages being flagged problematic by sucuri do return a 404 error. It seems I only need to configure my 404 handler and make sure they don't use http links. I would like to thank @stephenostermiller, @raulreyes and @patrickmevzek in helping me understand the problems.

PS: Google support also got in touch with me and told me that my website is clean and they'll be removing the malicious software tag from it soon.

Comment: If those files can get fetched from your domain when you own it, they aren't from the previous owners.  It sounds to me like your site got hacked.

Comment: Can you actually visit those files via URL? Do they return 200 header response? @Ajit?

Comment: When you point the domain to a new server, all the old files are no longer accessible and return "404 not found".     There isn't anything else to "clean up" on your site itself.   You shouldn't need to put in blank pages or redirect to your home page.

Comment: @RaulReyes No, those sites/webpages cannot actually be visited. But the crawlers are still somehow accessing them.

Comment: @Ajit how do you know they are accessing them?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller adding redirects and blank files did help me solve the mixed content issue i was facing on sucuri malware scans. because now those http calls which belonged to files of previous domain owner are now redirected to my website homepage, essentially making sure that no http calls are allowed on my website which runs https only.

Comment: @RaulReyes In cpanel on my webserver, there is a section where i can check the "visitors" their ip address, the pages and files they visit and some other related information. I am sure these files aren't my files because they are not present on my server, and theyre also not hidden files. I have searched them thoroughly. There are also some wordpress related files(which crawlers are accessing) which the previous owner must have used. I do not run my site on wordpress.

Comment: @Ajit what you are looking at is probably a bot or crawler request report, they are not really visiting you website, they are just requesting a previously crawled page and when they not find the requested file they get a 404 or not found server response. No need to worry they will eventually learn those files don’t exist anymore and stop requesting

Comment: @RaulReyes i find great assurance and agree with you to some extent. Except a sucuri scan determined that my website was making calls to another http link from files that do not exist in my root directory. And this was resolved easily when i set up blank files with same names and redirects to my homepage for those files. This is the reason i believe that somehow the crawlers are able to crawl the files that were added by previous domain owner and googles ads bots deem my website as malicious. I hope the bots learn quickly.

Comment: @Ajit please see my Anwser below, I would highly recommend using another approach on finding what is causing those calls, and remove the files created used as a temp solution, stop feeding the crawlers, they will keep coming back for more.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller
I did remove the temporary solutions and the mixed content problem is back. Could you please help me understand why the sucuri scan names 3 files(and the code using http calls within them) that are not present on my server? I have also attached the picture in the main question that i had posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website is `https://thewildfire.in/` (it would have been simpler to say so immediately at the start of your question insteady to rely on screenshots that are difficult to read, impossible to search on or to quote, even so much here that the important parts are just text lines that you could have pasted as is).

The software you show in screenshot seems to try some random not existing URLs such as `https://thewildfire.in/404javascript`. If you go there, and look at source code, you see:

```
    <script language="Javascript" src="http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php"></script>
```

This seems to be a default "404" handler that will generate a page for any random URL not existing, hence explaining your "which are not present on the root directory of my server,".

Try `https://thewildfire.in/foobar` and you will get the same page and same error.

Some security tool are testing random pages like that to search for vulnerabilities.

But this page served is reported as having "HTTP served in HTTPS"
because you are serving a page over HTTPS that includes elements (here a Javascript) served over HTTP. This should be fixed because nowadays browsers will at least flag that, if not even refuse to load this HTTP content, as otherwise it creates a security risk (the security of a whole system is the security of its weakest link: if you run "inside" and HTTPS page a Javascript downloaded over HTTP, this cancels the security you gained with HTTPS as that script over HTTP could have been completely hijacked in transit)

Your solutions in no specific order nor are they exclusive of each other:

- look if the above content served over HTTP can be served over HTTPS and if so, fix that URL
- look at your configuration and why you are serving those kind of pages in case of 404. Do you really need them? Specifically because right now besides showing a spinner they fail to do anything useful. Remove this specific "404" handler or have one not depending on HTTP resources.

All of this has nothing to do with previous content. Your **current** content is what is above and generates the errors of "HTTP in HTTPS".

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I also looked up the problematic links on my search console and on live testing confirmed that they do return 404 errors, which is a good thing.
It seems the only thing left to do is work on my 404 handler. I will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a new hosting for your website on another server than the one used before you owned the domain, you need to do **nothing**.

I would recommend using another approach to the one used to fix he sucuri reported issues. You need to find out, perhaps with Google ads support or search console reports why your website was flagged as malicious and use their recommended procedure to become thrustful again.

Going back to your concern, and judging by your comments, be aware that once you transfer your domain to a new host all files are removed automatically because your domain is not pointing to that old DNS anymore. If you want to recover this domain, you do not need to buy a new domain, once you improve the domain and website reputation you won’t need to worry about using your domain as it should.